# How do I return a type that's specified as a subtype of a specific class?

Tags: java

Essentially, I have an enum, and I want to return an instance of a class corresponding to that enum value. All of these instances are subclasses of a specific class. I'll show an example:

```
public Trait returnTrait(EnumX enum)
{
    switch (enum)
    {
        case EnumX.TRAITSUBCLASS1:
        {
            return new TraitSubClass1();
        }
        case EnumX.TRAITSUBCLASS2():
        {
            return new TraitSubClass2();
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I use the code above, the return is casted as a mere Trait, and the methods specific to its type are not available, only the methods from Trait are. How could I make this method's return type just classes that extend Trait? Would it be something like `Class<? extends Trait>` for the type?

Comment: You cannot really do what you want. You can make the method generic, but then you would run in the situation where a `ClassCastException` might occur. Why can't you work with a `Trait` on the calling side?

Comment: I'd be interested in the client code that actually uses your code. I don't know how it's going to try to call a subtype's method, if it doesn't even know the subtype yet.

Comment: Can you give an example of how you intend to *consume* this method?